# How to avoid double escape using XML

Tags: python, xml, escaping

I'm using python to make a program which will have to write data in a XML tag of a specific file.

The line of data I'm willing to write is the following.

```
&lt;Stream&gt;XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX?p=0&lt;/Stream&gt;&lt;URL&gt;rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2&lt;/URL&gt;
```

But what I get in my XML file after writing is pretty different.

```
&amp;lt;Stream&amp;gt;XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX?p=0&amp;lt;/Stream&amp;gt;&amp;lt;URL&amp;gt;rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2&amp;lt;/URL&amp;gt;
```

The &lt and &gt are here for purpose, and are NOT < and >. I need to keep this formatting but when I use the export as xml file, it replaces all the & by `&amp;`

I use this code to write data in the xml file:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

Name_with_single_quote= """IF [Calculation_1] = 'Day-1' THEN [begintime] + 1
ELSEIF[Calculation_1] < 'Day-2' THEN [begintime] + 2
ELSEIF  [Calculation_1] > "Day-3" THEN [begintime] + 3
ELSE [begintime]
END"""

Name_with_single_quote = Name_with_single_quote.replace("\n", "&#10;").replace("<", "&lt;").replace("'", "&apos;").replace(">","&gt;").replace("\"", "&quot;")
Name_with_single_quote = str(Name_with_single_quote)

xml = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<column role="dimension" type="nominal" name="[Calculation_1]" datatype="boolean" caption="">
<calculation formula=""/>
</column>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
formula = tree.find('.//calculation')
formula.set('formula', Name_with_single_quote)

from xml.dom import minidom
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(tree)).toprettyxml()
xmlstr = '\n'.join(list(filter(lambda x: len(x.strip()), xmlstr.split('\n'))))
with open('test_for_esc_result.xml', "w") as f:
    f.write(xmlstr)
```

Comment: convert it to raw string

Comment: Do not do string replacement (`s.replace("<", "&lt;")`). If you want `&lt;` in the XML output, use `<` in the input. lxml or minidom will do the escaping for you.